# gwt modal popuppanel blocks iframe event

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT application with a simple "please wait" mechanism. When I press a button to send a RPC call, I put on the sceen a modal popup dialog which blocks the user interaction until the RPC returns. Like this I prevent the user from clicking multiple times on the button and sending multiple RPCs. This works perfectly, except when when loading an IFrame. In this case, the loadhandler I install on the iframe is never called.

```
/**
 * Test class
 */
public class Test implements EntryPoint {

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(false, true);
        popup.add(new Label("Please wait"));
        popup.center();

        final Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com");
        frame.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                Window.alert("Event received");
                popup.hide();
            }
        });

        RootPanel.get().add(frame);
    }
}
```

However, if I construct a PopupPanel(false, false), then the LoadEvent is triggered. 
Note: this only occurs in the compiled mode, not in the GWT development mode.

Does anybody have a clue?

Thank you in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `modal` popup, there are [all sorts of issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6455) with it. Prefer displaying the glass panel (`setGlassEnabled`).

Answer (score 0):

Modal windows prevent various events in order to ensure modality. That beign the case you need to find a workaround.

I would suggest to disable the button on click and enable it on success or failure of the rpc.

If you need to disable them all a once then you would most probably need to implement your own Events, register them in the event bus and handle them according to your needs.